# Eclipse is always losing it's icons which causes endless pop-ups

Tags: eclipse

I have to deal with this problem periodically.  Somehow I'm able to fix it but then it comes back and I forget what I did, so I am putting this out there so that others who have this issue can have some relief and I can find the solution to it next time it happens.  Eclipse will lose icons for certain things (right now it is the icon for .jar files) and this causes a Java null-pointer exception dialog box to pop-up if you click on it or Eclipse accesses that resource.  It will also lose icons for other things. Here I click on the "one-jar" jar file.  It results in the dialog box shown.

[image: Clicking on something where an icon does not display]

Something else occasionally occurs with the list of editors when you click on "Open With".  This time it is not causing any problems except loss of hair on my end.  Right now I am using Oxygen Release Milestone 2 (4.7.0 M2).  It happens with prior releases as well.  Closing and restarting does not help any.

[image: Missing Open-With icons]

Comment: I wonder if the disk you are using to store Eclipse is having read errors. Have you done a check disk on that disk?

Comment: I have scheduled a check disk on next boot up.  I am using a new SSHD however.

Comment: M2 means milestone 2, which was a very early preview build and might be unstable. Please upgrade to Eclipse Oxygen.3 (4.7.3).

Comment: If you download a new copy of eclipse and install it on your computer. Beside the existing one (its easy to do). Does it happen to the other one? I think @howlger is on to something with that suggestion.

Comment: Looks like (for now) Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3) is gonna behave.  Will keep everyone posted.  Thanks!